# Server side only JWT signing with X509Certificate2

Tags: jwt, signing, bearer-token, x509certificate2

I am creating a JWT and signing (not encrypting) it using a X509Certificate stored in the private cert store on the server.

```
var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new X509SecurityKey(nameOfX509Certificate2), 
SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature);

var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
{
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
    new Claim("Admin", "YES", ClaimValueTypes.String)
    }),
    Audience = "ValidAudience",
    Issuer = "ValidIssuer",
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5),
    SigningCredentials = signingCredentials
};

JwtSecurityToken stoken = null;
var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
stoken = tokenHandler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(tokenDescriptor);

var jwt = tokenHandler.WriteToken(stoken);
```

This is done server side and the token is only ever shared server side with applications on other servers etc.. so no client side signing is done.
My question is, at this point, is the public key in the cert being used for signing? It is my assumption this is the case because we are using Asymmetric RSASHA256 algorithm?

Below is the code for verifying the token, again server side, using the same certificate used to sign it originally.
So it is my assumption is that the private key is used to verify the token by the receiving application....correct?

```
jwt = "eyJxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...."

var signingKey = MyCertificateHelper.SigningKey(nameOfX509Certificate2); // Returns X509SecurityKey
var decryptKey = MyCertificateHelper.DecryptKey(nameOfX509Certificate2);   // Returns X509SecurityKey

//Set up the parameters to validate the token
var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidAudiences = new[] { "ValidAudience" },
    ValidIssuers = new[] { "ValidIssuer" },
    IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
    TokenDecryptionKey = decryptKey
};

// SecurityToken validatedToken;
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
principal = handler.ValidateToken(jwt, tokenValidationParameters, validatedToken: out var validatedToken);
```

No this works fine, I just want to clear up the key used in the cert for both signing and verification as I am seeing conflicting statements.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In asymmetric cryptography:

Encryption:

- Public key is used to encrypt content
- Private key is used to decrypt content

Signing:

- Private key is used to sign content
- Public key is used to verify signature

Both your assumptions are opposite.